# Mongodb $exists query produces empty result

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection like this:

```
[{
    _id: 'XXX',
    name: 'Foo',
    device: {
        android: 'SOME_STRING'
    }
},{
    _id: 'XXZ',
    name: 'BAR',
    device: {
        ios: 'SOME_DIFFERENT_STRING'
    }
}]
```

I want to query for items that are either android or ios devices. So:

```
var query = {
    device : {
        android: {
            $exists: true
        }
    }
}

collection.find(query)
```

However this query always gives me an empty result although there are items with device.android in the database.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong form of query. You need [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/):

```js
db.collection.find({ "device.android": { "$exists": true } })
```

The reason being that the nested object form is far to explicit for the query engine and at the first level it is looking for an "exact" match. So the "$exists" gets treated as a literal rather than a query operator.

Comment: +1 absolutely! Thank you :)

Comment: @artworkadシ Glad that answered your question. And explained why as well